# Good sample application for android service

Tags: android, android-service

Is there a good sample application or tutorial for creating android `Service` that run in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't know any apart from my own application. But that is real applications with all the extra code that comes with it and not sample as such.

If you still want to have a go you I suggest you look for **Service_Intend** and **Service_Connection** in [Calculator_Activity.java](http://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/uiq3/branches/Symbian/JavaME/Calculator-Droid/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/uiq3/calculator/Calculator_Activity.java?revision=4236&view=markup) and for **Calculator_Thread** and **Binder** in [Calculator_Service.java](http://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/uiq3/branches/Symbian/JavaME/Calculator-Droid/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/uiq3/calculator/Calculator_Service.java?revision=4236&view=markup). That should give you some idea.

Answer (score 6):

The Android API Demos include a [Remote Service sample](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).  I think we used it as the starting point for our background service.  There is also example code right in [the documentation for the Service class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).